# Selecting the rows of table of ms word file through c#

Tags: c#

I have a table which is in ms word .i need to fill the rows with some data through c#.

I was thinking to fill through array or list or some other data sources.

But the challenge is how to select the first row of the table, there are n number of tables is in my word file.

Comment: Please provide more details. what have you tried so far?

Comment: i created merge fields on the first row of a table and pushed the data to those mergefields through xml,so my headers are ready ,now i need to fill the data according to the column name ..(hope u got?)

Answer (score 0):

What type of libary are you using ? Try DocX https://docx.codeplex.com/. 
It has great table integration. You can use a template file or a file as a template and create a new table. That way you dont need to worry about table indexin. Or you can use text replacement and fill the tables in the template file whit placeholders.

Comment: Shawn  OpenSettings openSetting = new OpenSettings();
            openSetting.AutoSave = true;
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true, openSetting))
            { } m opeaning the doocument and looking for placeholders(mergefields) to select the coulmn name

Comment: How to create a table whit DocX http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/06/docx-and-tables.html The only difference is that you would load a template insead of creating a new file.

Comment: I'm not bothering about creating the tables..end users create the table in ms word, i want access to it  through c# , i' m going to use memory stream and looking for place holders then i put the name to it ,so that it becomes  the table header. now i need to fill the data into it.so their i m feeling problem